# githubactions - copy/upload file to windows based ec2-instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am using GitHub actions to build a .NET MVC framework based application.

I am able to build it successfully but unable to copy the resultant `.exe` file to Windows based ec2-instance, since I cant ssh into it.

I have looked for plugins but unable to find any.
Is there any plugin or way to do that from GitHub actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering an article like "[Deploy to AWS EC2 using GitHub Actions](https://lightrains.com/blogs/deploy-aws-ec2-using-github-actions/)"  (from [niksmac](https://twitter.com/niksmac_), also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827525/niksmac)) suggests to use SSH to deploy, the first avenue would be to activate SSH on your Windows EC2 instance.

According to "[Can we SSH to Windows EC2 instance in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842445/6309)" through [using OpenSSH on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui).
From there, you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66661512/6309) an SSH deploy in action.